# MySQL: Update all rows in a table matching results of another query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've written a query returning rows associating **Customers and Salespeoeple**.

Note that the query joins several database tables. And note that not all customers have a salesperson.

```
c_id     c_name   s_id   s_name
  24  microsoft      1     mike
  27        sun      1     mike
  42      apple      2     bill
  44     oracle      1     mike
  47        sgi      1     mike
  58       ebay      2     bill
  61     paypal      3      joe
  65     redhat      1     mike
```

I also have a single table (called **invoices**) in my database that looks like this.

```
i_id   c_id   c_name   s_id   s_name
7208     22   toyota   NULL     NULL
7209     23     ford   NULL     NULL
7210     27      sun   NULL     NULL
7211     42    apple   NULL     NULL
7212     12   nissan   NULL     NULL
7213     15       gm   NULL     NULL
7214     61   paypal   NULL     NULL
```

How can I use UPDATE in MySQL to make my invoices table look like the table below?

```
i_id   c_id   c_name   s_id   s_name
7208     22   toyota   NULL     NULL
7209     23     ford   NULL     NULL
7210     27      sun      1     mike
7211     42    apple      2     bill
7212     12   nissan   NULL     NULL
7213     15       gm   NULL     NULL
7214     61   paypal      3      joe
```

That is to say, how can I update my invoice table to include the correct salesperson_id and salesperson_name, where that relationship exists?

Note that where a Customer/Salesperson relationship exists, all invoices for that customer should have the salesperson associated with it, if there is a salesperson for that customer.

Thanks kindly :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### Using subqueries

Most widely supported option

```
UPDATE INVOICES
   SET s_id = (SELECT cs.s_id
                 FROM CUSTOMERS_AND_SALES cs
                WHERE cs.c_id = INVOICES.c_id),
       s_name = (SELECT cs.s_name
                   FROM CUSTOMERS_AND_SALES cs
                  WHERE cs.c_id = INVOICES.c_id)
 WHERE INVOICES.c_id IN (SELECT cs.s_id
                           FROM CUSTOMERS_AND_SALES cs)
```

### Using JOINs

```
UPDATE INVOICES
  JOIN CUSTOMERS_AND_SALES cs ON cs.c_id = INVOICES.c_id
   SET s_id = cs.s_id,
       s_name = cs.s_name
```

Comment: The joins options is absolutely beautiful. Thanks so much :) Just needed to replace "CUSTOMERS_AND_SALES" with "(SELECT blah from blah blah blah)".

Comment: Really nice example. Especially the second example which use JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your first table is named `customers` and those customers without a salesperson have an `s_id` of `NULL`

```
UPDATE invoices JOIN customers USING (c_id)
SET invoices.s_id = customers.s_id, invoices.s_name = customers.s_name
WHERE customers.s_id IS NOT NULL;
```

I suggest testing in development or running a `SELECT` query using the `JOIN` above first to ensure the results.

Comment: not working for 11g ORA-00971: كلمة الأساس SET مفقودة

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view to make your `UPDATE` statement simple. The view should contain your query (in your case the query that associates customers and salespeople). Then update your table (`invoices` in your case) like this:

```
update TableToUpdate ttu, MyView mv
set ttu.column = mv.column
where ttu.key = mv.key
```

Comment: not working for 11g ORA-00971: كلمة الأساس SET  مفقودة